# Determining Video Length from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-streaming

Is it possible to determine the length of a video in a memory stream without saving the file to disk and using WMP or Shell?

Not the size but the actual playing time of the video?

In this case the user uploads a video to the site and I write it to a MemoryStream. I have heard that I can access the metadata concerning the length of the video if the file is on disk but ideally I would like to not to have to save the file first but instead get this metadata from the stream so I can then reject it if it is over say, 10 minutes in length.

The only examples I have seen are either using WMP or Windows Shell but both require a file on disk. How would I go about getting the playing time from the stream?

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Yes it's possible but you have to narrow the question down if you want specific details.